# Refer to current package's root name

Tags: rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the best way to refer to the name of the package's root folder?

For example, if I had a package named `X` and I wanted to read files from, e.g., the `bag` subfolder (i.e. `X/bag`) from either inside a script under `scripts` (i.e. `X/scripts/read_file_from_bag_subfolder.py`) or from a module under `src` (e.g. `src/X/read_file_from_bag_subfolder.py`), what would be the best way to do it?

I know I can use `rospack` as I explained here http://wiki.ros.org/Packages, but that requires you to manually specify the name of the current package, but if it changes, then you would also need to change that code, so maybe a relative way of doing it would be better, even though this may also cause problems if you decide to move your code to another subfolder.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260079/refer-to-current-package%27s-root-name/) by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 372 on 2017-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because of the relatively loose coupling between a source file and the package it resides it, I don't think it is easy to find out the package name from within the source file. You could do it by looking for specific parent directories, but this will need to be different depending on if the file has been installed or not (if not, then look for the nearest parent with a `package.xml` file, if so and installed like a binary then look for the immediate parent directory of the executable). I think this is very fragile, however.

If you don't want to hard-code the package name, which is understandable, and would prefer not to use relative paths inside the package (which might break if the package gets installed), then the best I can come up with is to receive the package name as a command line argument or a ROS parameter inside the script. Then you can specify the package name on the command line or in the launch file. This is really only moving the hard-coding somewhere else, though, and if the script is intended to be run from the command line it would be a pain to use. I think that if the script is always run from a launch file, I would consider putting the package name in a parameter but I do not think the maintenance trade-off is that beneficial. If it's run from the command line, I would personally prefer to hard-code the package name in the script.

By the way, the [resource_retriever](http://wiki.ros.org/resource_retriever) package is often useful when loading resources, both local and remote. (It won't solve your hard-code-the-package-name problem, though.)

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll refer to roscpp, but I expect the same goes for rospy.

You can use `ros::package::getPath("<my-package-name>")` to get the path to `<my-package-name>`. You'll have to include `ros/package.h`.

If you think your package name is going to change, then add a parameter to the parameter server and retrieve the name from there.

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.ros.org/users/20033/nlamprian/) with karma: 366 on 2017-04-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2017-04-24**:
Did you read all my question? I mentioned I know there's a way to do it using the `rospack` module (in Python), which is equivalent to the C++ code you're mentioning, which is also reported in that same article I'm linking you to.